# How to tell if fb_var_screeninfo changes without polling

Tags: c, linux, polling

Playing with the linux framebuffer.  Instead of

```c
while(TRUE) {
  ioctl(fd, FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO, var);
}
```

(where `var` is an `fb_var_screeninfo` struct)  I would like to do

```c
// wait_for_change blocks and does nothing until 
// the framebuffer's variable screen info changes
while(var = wait_for_change(fd, FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO));
```

Anyone know how?

EDIT: more generally, I'm asking how to be notified about changes to framebuffer resolution.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  I mean, it doesn't just randomly switch modes; something must effect the change.  This is why there doesn't seem to be an interface for that, the proper way is to have the changers notify your program when they do so:  co-operation.  If you want to wait for a change, just poll it but nanosleep() 10 - 100ms in between.  If you are doing a screen capture, then do it before and after copying the frame buffer memory, but discard and redo it if necessary.

Comment: @None I'm kicking around the idea of writing a terminal for the framebuffer and I want it to respond to screen resolution changes by eg fbset.  Read more about my motivation here. https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/75336/68380

Comment: In that case, you just do the ioctl before each display update.  But... Java? Really? Do not expect it to gain any popularity, then...  With C, you'd have FreeType.  With C++ or Python, you could use [Qt on top of the framebuffer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/embedded-linux.html#linuxfb) directly, without X.

Comment: Thanks.  I took a shot at learning C earlier in the year and the experience was frustrating.  Almost no feedback https://www.reddit.com/r/C_Programming/comments/ei6jup/mergesort_critique_experience_report/ .

Comment: I don't use reddit/facebook/twitter, so I wouldn't know.  You might try cboard.cprogramming.com.  Java is not too popular in Linux, especially embedded.  As to the generic interface, the standard library already provides a generic quicksort, [qsort()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html). First parameter is the array (or pointer to first element), second is the number of elements, third is the size of each element in bytes (`sizeof`), and the fourth is the function to use to compare two elements.

Comment: I created an example [`msort()`](https://pastebin.com/cLknPdHJ) (Pastebin link) merge sort that uses the C `qsort()` interface, in case you are interested.  When compiled and run, it converts command-line arguments to numbers (doubles), and compares the results to `qsort()`.  The last parameter is the work area pointer; if NULL, a temporary area is allocated.

Comment: Hey man, I'm not going to leave you hanging after all that effort. I'll definitely look over that code. Thanks!